# App.router must be provided to createNavigationPropConstructor

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, redux-thunk

I'm getting this error after upgrading react-navigation and redux-helpers libraries to latest versions, still unable to find any useful link.

- "react": "16.3.1",
- "react-native": "0.55.4",
- "react-navigation": "^2.3.1",
- "react-navigation-redux-helpers": "^2.0.1",

  Invariant Violation: App.router must be provided to createNavigationPropConstructor as of react-navigation-redux-helpers@2.0.0. Learn more: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/redux-integration.html#breaking-changes-in-2.3

  ```
  This error is located at:
      in NavigatorReduxWrapper (created by Connect(NavigatorReduxWrapper))
      in Connect(NavigatorReduxWrapper) (at App.js:27)
      in Provider (at App.js:26)
      in App (at renderApplication.js:33)
      in RCTView (at View.js:60)
      in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
      in RCTView (at View.js:60)
      in View (at AppContainer.js:122)
      in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:32)
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The error is likely due to the somewhat incorrect and misleading docs you linked above causing the improper use of `reduxifyNavigator`, i.e. passing in a plain ol' `Component` instead of a `NavigationContainer`.

Check out this solution, posted a few weeks ago
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation-redux-helpers/issues/44#issuecomment-400480935